# Inject command on process running linux

Tags: linux, bash, process, debian

Is it possible to inject certain code into an application running using the command line?
I explain myself: I want to change an effect of the cheese application without the need to click on "effects" and then click on the effect I need. I want to do something like inject a command that changes the effect and that command I shortcut the keyboard so that when I press a key I change the effect.

Thank you very much!

Greetings

Comment: Probably, but that's rather complicated. Better modify cheese itself (download its source, add required functionality, build, use your custom build of cheese).

Comment: You could use something like `xdotool` to automate mouse clicks. I haven't used it enough to provide any more guidance.